# Not allow Jquery button submit to happen twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

I've stumbled upon a YouTube API which shows YouTube videos on search. Great! But here's the thing: when I click on a button once, all the videos show up. But when I click on them again and again, the SAME videos show.

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="search" id="search" style='text-align: center; font-family: FontAwesome;' placeholder="&#xf002; Search...">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
<script>
function tplawesome(e,t){res=e;for(var n=0;n<t.length;n++){res=res.replace(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/g,function(e,r){return t[n][r]})}return res}
$(function() {
  $("form").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //prepare the request
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
        part: "snippet",
        type: "video",
        q: encodeURIComponent($("#search").val()).replace(/%20/g, "+"),
        maxResults: 10,
        order: "viewCount",
        safeSearch: "strict"
    });
    request.execute(function(response) {
      var results = response.result;
      $.each(results.items, function(index,item) {
        $.get("item.html", function(data) {
          $("#results").append(tplawesome(data, [{"title":item.snippet.title, "videoid":item.id.videoId}]));
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
function init() {
  gapi.client.setApiKey("APIKEY");
  gapi.client.load("youtube", "v3", function() {
    //YT Api is ready
  });
}
```

There aren't any errors in the script, I'm just entering it into Stack Overflow weirdly. So again, how to stop people from clicking the button again and showing the EXACT same 10 videos again? I was thinking of using location.reload();,  but this just removes all the videos that are supposed to be shown.

Comment: why would you do that exactly how many people keep loading stackoverflow page again and again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Just either remove or disable that button.

- **Remove:** `$('[name="submit"]').remove();`
- Or **Disable:** `$('[name="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);`

---

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    .
    .
    request.execute(function(response) {
        var results = response.result;
        $.each(results.items, function(index,item) {
            $.get("item.html", function(data) {
                $("#results").append(tplawesome(data, [{"title":item.snippet.title, "videoid":item.id.videoId}]));
            });
        });

        $('[name="submit"]').remove(); // Or $('[name="submit"]').prop('disabled', true); 
    });        
});
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: it might be helpful to enable the button again if the search input changes.

Comment: @showdev yes, because of that I've suggested *Either remove or disable that button*